# What is the ~/.rnd file in openssl and how to generate a new private key with it?

Tags: ssl-certificate, openssl

When I tried to run the following command to issue a new private key, which I use to host my web app via SSL:

```
openssl genrsa -out example.key 2048
```

the following error occured:

```
unable to write 'random state'  
e is 65537 (0x10001)
```

After digging out on the Web, I found [a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94445/using-openssl-what-does-unable-to-write-random-state-mean), which instructs you to delete the `~/.rnd` file, which is likely owned by `root`.

```
sudo rm ~/.rnd
```

However, I found you don't need to delete the `~/.rnd` if you issue the `openssl` command with `sudo`.

So my question is:

- what is the `~/.rnd` and why does it exist in my environment?
- Which is a better way to issue a new private key?

Comment: `~/.rnd` should be owned by the user of the home directory. It should only be owned by root if it's root's `/root/.rnd`. The wrong ownership would explain the "unable to write error".

Comment: @jscott Yeah I know. My question is why it has been created as `root` (and what it does), which seems to be true as well of people in the linked question.

Comment: It seems the obvious guess would be "root created the file or `chown`d it for some reason." -- that part would be for you to solve. None of the user profiles I checked here have it owned by root. The file is somewhat detailed in [`man 1 sslrand`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sslrand).

Answer (score 12):

The `~/.rnd` file is owned by `root` if you've ever run a command that modifies `~/.rnd` as `root` via sudo in its non-login mode (ie without `-i`).  As for what the `~/.rnd` file is, it contains a seed value for the OpenSSL random number generator.  The least-worst docs I can find on it are [the `RAND_read_file`(3) man page](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/crypto/RAND_load_file.html).

Comment: fwiw, the latest (”master“) version of the manpage is available at https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/RAND_load_file.html